# Python Script Zonal Stats as Table Loop Question

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, zonal-statistics, loop

I'm trying to write a small script loop script which retrieves rasters from each folder, performs zonal statistics using watershed polygons and saves it as a table. I've written similar loop scripts, but this seems to be confusing me. Here's what I have so far:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *
env.workspace = "F:/lu_crop_rast"
arcpy.env.overwriteoutput = 1

watershedFeat = "F:/watersheds.shp"
outDir = "F:/lu_crop_rast/tables/"

for raster in arcpy.ListRasters():
    outTable = outDir + raster + "_TBL.dbf"
    arcpy.sa.ZonalStatisticsAsTable(watershedFeat,"Name",raster,outTable,"NODATA","MEAN")
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "<string>", line 15, in <module>   File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py", line 6232, in ZonalStatisticsAsTable     statistics_type)   
File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Utils.py", line 53, in swapper     result = wrapper(*args, **kwargs)   File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py", line 6224, in Wrapper     statistics_type)   
File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 504, in <lambda>     return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True)) ExecuteError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function. Create output table failed Failed to execute (ZonalStatisticsAsTable).
```

I've checked and my rasters and shapefile aren't corrupt. I've looked at this [thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/164224/batch-zonal-statistics-as-table) as well and made the following changes:

```
arcpy.gp.ZonalStatisticsAsTable_sa(watershedFeat,"Name",raster,outTable,"NODATA","MEAN")
```

But so far nothing seems to work.

Comment: Try fixing your indentations in the for loop first and see if you get the same error (need to dedent)

Comment: I think the indentation was just a matter of copying/pasting. Besides, over-indenting is actually accepted by Python; it doesn't throw an error--and if it did, it wouldn't throw an error within the geoprocessing function.

Comment: Depending on the data types of your input rasters, this could be failing because you are assigning a second extension.

Comment: Yes, because I ended up manually performing zonal stats on some of the rasters to check if that was the issue. The output table had valid entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to dedent and modify your naming (thanks Tom). Try this:

```
import arcpy, os
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
```

-

```
for raster in arcpy.ListRasters():
    raster_name = os.path.basename(raster).rstrip(os.path.splitext(raster)[1])
    outTable = outDir + raster_name + "_TBL.dbf"
    arcpy.gp.ZonalStatisticsAsTable(watershedFeat,"Name",raster,outTable,"NODATA","MEAN")
```

Comment: Yes, Tom is correct. The over-indenting is because of copying and pasting the code. It is now fixed.

Comment: I updated my answer - try the code above

Comment: Thanks! This runs the loop successfully. It is likely an issue with the ".tif" file extension. Now, I'm running into another problem where zonal stats aren't being calculated for some of the individual watersheds. Would setting the extent and mask solve this issue?

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to set your environments, but I suspect that's not the problem. Are you sure there are raster data present for each watershed?