# Zonal statistics for several rasters in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, zonal-statistics, error-999999

I am running this Zonal Statistics as a Table code for a single raster and it works:

```
import arcpy, os 
destination_path= r'\\Mac\Home\Desktop\arc_stuff' 
shapefile= r'\\Mac\Home\Desktop\arc_stuff\subfolder1\adm_shp_all_selection.shp'
arcpy.env.workspace=r'\\Mac\Home\Desktop\arc_stuff' 
raster='lights_1992.tif'
outZSaT = arcpy.gp.ZonalStatisticsAsTable_sa(shapefile, "unique_id", raster,'lights_1992.dbf',"DATA","SUM")
```

I'll have to process many rasters, hence I tried building the loop below, but I always get this error:

```
ERROR 999999: Error executing function. Create output table failed Failed to execute (ZonalStatisticsAsTable).
```

This is the loop:

```
import os
import arcpy, os
destination_path=r'\\Mac\Home\Desktop\arc_stuff\output' 
shapefile= r'\\Mac\Home\Desktop\arc_stuff\subfolder1\adm_shp_all_selection.shp'
arcpy.env.workspace=r'\\Mac\Home\Desktop\arc_stuff'
rasters = arcpy.ListRasters("lights_*.tif")
for raster in rasters:
    print('Destination Path: %s\nRaster: %s\nDestination File: %s\n' % (destination_path, raster, destination_file))
    destination_file = os.path.join(destination_path, raster + ".dbf")
    outZSaT = arcpy.gp.ZonalStatisticsAsTable_sa(shapefile, "unique_id", raster, destination_file,"DATA","SUM")
```

I am aware of this related thread: [Batch Zonal Statistics as table?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/164224/batch-zonal-statistics-as-table), but I think the issues pointed out there do not apply to my problem.

Who can help?

Comment: Does your code work if you copy your data to a local drive?

Comment: For the single raster yes, for the loop no.

Comment: I have a couple things for you to try:  "from arcpy.sa import *";   "arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")"; "outZSat = ZonalStatisticsAsTable(shapefile, "unique_id", raster, destination_file,"DATA","SUM")"

Comment: Also try creating a feature layer from the shapefile and using that as your 'In_zone_data".  It specifies that it only accepts a raster layer or feature layer.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to check out the extension.

Also, the in_zone_data only accepts a raster layer or feature layer.  I've edited your code to include these changes.

Try changing your code to this:

```
import os
import arcpy
from arcpy.sa import *
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
destination_path=r'\\Mac\Home\Desktop\arc_stuff\output' 
shapefile= r'\\Mac\Home\Desktop\arc_stuff\subfolder1\adm_shp_all_selection.shp'
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(shapefile,"layer")
layer = arcpy.mapping.Layer("layer")
arcpy.env.workspace=r'\\Mac\Home\Desktop\arc_stuff'
rasters = arcpy.ListRasters("lights_*.tif")
for raster in rasters:
    print('Destination Path: %s\nRaster: %s\nDestination File: %s\n' % (destination_path, raster, destination_file))
    destination_file = os.path.join(destination_path, raster + ".dbf")
    outZSat = ZonalStatisticsAsTable(layer, "unique_id", raster, destination_file,"DATA","SUM")
```